# create windows 10 install usb on ubuntu

Tags: windows-10, boot, bootable-media

I have an ubuntu 20.04 installation and am trying to multiboot windows next to it.

I've created an usb drive (8gb) and downloaded the windows 10 iso.

Formatting the usb flash drive with "exfat" and then copying the contents of the iso to the usb drive.

However once I restart my pc I do not see the usb drive anywhere in the boot order.

I'm using a gigabyte z690 ud ddr4 (rev 1.0) motherboard.

Comment: Ages ago, I had an EXFAT drive that Windows 10 simply wouldn't recognize. It might be simpler to use a FAT formatted drive.

Comment: @Anaksunaman some files are larger than 4GB (install.wim for example).

Comment: @DrMoishePippik if I format as ntfs unetbootin doesn't see the usb drive.

Answer (score 1):

Most PC's BIOS *do not recognize exFAT-formatted media.* exFAT is a proprietary file system, and even Linux needs [fuse](https://pkgs.org/download/exfat-fuse) to work with it. Therefore, the flash USB drive should be formatted FAT32. Here are two suggestions for making a Windows installation on a FAT32-formatted USB drive **under Linux**:

1. Apparently, [an older version of the Windows Media Creation Tool runs well in wine](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=20264).

   - Download the [2004 version of Windows Media Creation Tool](https://www.itechtics.com/windows-10-version-2004/).
   - Download [Windows 10 Version 2004 (20H1)](https://www.itechtics.com/?dl_id=85).
   - Plug in the flash drive.
   - Run the tool under *wine* to create the flash boot USB.
   - Install the *old* Windows OS, and then update it -- a lengthy process.
2. Because of the 4 GB FAT32 file-size limitation, [the .wim file can be compressed during installation](https://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/windows-10-usb-media-linux.html), and expanded upon installation.

   - Download the latest Windows ISO form Microsoft.
   - Mount the ISO and extract the .wim file.
   - Get [wimlib](https://wimlib.net/). In Ubuntu, run `sudo apt install wimtools` in Terminal.
   - Compress the .win in Terminal: `sudo wimlib-imagex optimize install.wim --solid`. *sudo* may be needed because the .wim is write-only. This should compress the file to ~3/4 it's original size.
   - Now the ISO, with ~3.3 GB install.wim, should be put on the USB [using Terminal](https://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/windows-10-usb-media-linux.html) or [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.github.io/) or [other application](https://alternativeto.net/software/unetbootin/?platform=linux).

However, if you have access to a Windows OS PC, it is **far easier to download the latest Media Creation Tool, and use it to fetch the ISO and make the boot USB device.**

[Comment: It seems Microsoft is moving from an open OS to one a bit more closed, where applications are downloaded *via* their store (or rented to be used online), and where *booting* another OS is discouraged.]

Answer (score 0):

Did you mount the ISO and copy the files from the mounted ISO? Remember that an ISO file is just an archive like a .zip. If you copy the windows.iso file to the flash media your system wont know what to do with it, becuase the files are still compressed and archived. Make sure you mount the windows.iso file in your linux distro first then copy the contents of the file to the USB. This will copy over the data the PC needs to recognize that the USB is bootable.

Check this link out: [How to Create a Bootable Windows 10 USB in Linux](https://itsfoss.com/bootable-windows-usb-linux/)
 it gives you a couple different ways of creating bootable media in Linux.

Comment: yes I did. As well as use unetbootin - which allows me to boot but then gives an error with files not correct (install.wim).

Comment: interesting. I assume that you are also using GPT as the partitioning table when creating the bootable media?